# android work with an intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am having problems to work with an intent. Debugger crashes at last following line. However, If I set a breakpoint at this line, myVar1 is properly filled but when executing this line program crashes. Thank you.

from main class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myPush.class);

intent.putExtra("myVar1", var1);

startActivity(intent);
```

and from myPush class

```
String recVar = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myVar1");
```

EDIT: already tried with `Intent(this, myPush.class)` and `Intent(currentClass.this, myPush.class)` and same result!

debbuger doesn't say too much...

```
03-14 14:28:48.887: W/dalvikvm(2595): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
```

Comment: Try to change `getBaseContext()` to `this`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `String recVar = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myVar1");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change getBasecontext() to a.this . Where a = the activity class you
>   are in.

Also don't forget to put the class you want to transfer to in your androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Which line phrase did the debugger stop on?

Comment: In the AndroidManifest.xml did you put the activity inside  another activity eg. <Activity> <Activity> </Activity> </Activity>. That wont work if it is placed in that order. <Activity> </Activity> then <Activity> </Activity> should work.

Comment: stopped at String recVar = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myVar1"); and nop, separete activities as you suggest

Comment: Okay so you are able to switch classes. That's good. Did you verify in the previous class that var1 has an item?  If so did you make sure the type you are getting it is in string or integer? Since I am seeing rectVar which may be a rectangular variable which could be an int. Assumingly speaking.

Comment: cleaned and tested on a real device, same issue. "recVar" means recived and both are strings :(

Comment: so is recVar null? on the previous activity?. I suggest rechecking all your variables again. Transferring activity doesn't look like the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myPush.class);
```

use instead

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , myPush.class);
```

or you can use

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CLASS.this , myPush.class);
```

I think your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, myPush.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you do it like this, as long as the context changes didn't result:

Intent intent = new getIntent();
String recVar = intent.getStringExtra("myVar1");